# Did John the Evangelist refer to himself as `the disciple whom Jesus loved 'in retrospect?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-john, john-apostle

We see John the Evangelist referring to himself as `the disciple whom Jesus loved' , four times in the Gospel (Vs  13:23, 19:26, 21:7 and 21:20), the first reference being to the conversation at Last Supper :

> One of them, the disciple whom Jesus loved, was reclining next to him.

The first time we see Jesus giving a special consideration to John is when the Lord entrusts the care of his mother to John ( 19:26) . In the Gospel accounts preceding that incident, we do not see any special consideration given by Jesus to John. On the contrary, Jesus disappoints John and James who come to him demanding 'VIP seats' in glory (Mk 10: 35-40)   One is, therefore, inclined to believe that John, at the time  of writing the Gospel, thought deeply about the event at the foot of the Cross,and considered himself to have been  'the  special disciple' right from the beginning. In other words, John was referring to himself as 'the disciple whom Jesus loved' in retrospect. My question therefore, is: According to Catholic scholars, did John the Evangelist refer to himself as 'the disciple whom Jesus loved' in retrospect?

Comment: "we do not see any special consideration given by Jesus to John" - I don't agree, we see Peter, James and John treated specially: only they were with Jesus when Jairus' daughter was resurrected, when He transfigured on the mountain and they were singled out to be close to Him in Getsemani garden. John and Peter are tasked with preparing the last Supper. John was lying on Jesus' chest during the Last Supper. I don't know the answer to your question, but I think the general consensus is that John really was beloved disciple and he chose to refer to himself like that to avoid writing his name.

Comment: Thanks, Yksisarvinen. Your point that John chose to refer to himself as `the disciple whom Jesus loved' to avoid writing his name, stands reason. But by doing so, he took the risk of prompting the others to say:  " What is this John, did not Jesus love us too ? "